# how to keep live reload when dockerizing my angular app

Tags: angular, docker

so i'm new to docker, i've been trying to dockerize my angular app,
I have some issue with ng serve in my docker container running by docker-compose.
here's dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm i
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli --unsafe

COPY . /usr/src/app


CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

and here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        build:
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: dockerfile
        volumes:
            - './app'
            - './app/node_modules'
        ports:
            - '4201:4200'
```

everything works great, however when edit any file i don't get any live reload on docker container, i have to restart the container to get changes.
i'm using linux debian 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've come across this problem in the past where my docker container's file state doesn't match my local file state, it usually means that your `volumes` and your docker entry point should match up.

For example, in your `Dockerfile` you're moving all your local files to `/usr/src/app`.

However, in your `docker-compose.yml` you're moving them to `/app` instead of the matching `/usr/src/app` you've defined in your `Dockerfile`.

My advice is to try sticking to just moving to `/app` throughout both definitions.

Comment: thank you for your response, can you please tell me how to do so ?

Comment: edited my response. It's easier to read than in the comments section

Comment: I've made a gist - maybe try that: https://gist.github.com/ctrlaltdylan/16db454c4f50226b2d1936c0a3ba963b

Comment: well, i've solved it long ago and it seems to be the same as u're solution so i'll mark ur answer as a solution, thank you again for your time